# What does the word "popping" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Here is a sentence from a match-three game:

> In all levels, you've got tasks to complete – such as **popping** a certain number of blue dots.

I am not sure about the meaning of the word popping here. Which of the following meanings mentioned in the Merriam Webster fits here?

Transitive 1 : to strike or knock sharply : HIT 2 : to push, put, or thrust suddenly and often deftly pops a grape into her mouth popped in a CD 3 : to cause to explode or burst open popped some popcorn pop the trunk 4 : to fire at : SHOOT 5 : to take (pills) especially frequently or habitually 6 : to open with a pop pop a cold beer

intransitive verb

1a : to go, come, or appear suddenly —often used with up images popping up on the screen pop in for a visit b : to escape or break away from something (such as a point of attachment) usually suddenly or unexpectedly c : to be or become striking or prominent colors that pop … a mild sauce punctuated with tiny dried shrimp that pop with salinity. — John Kessler 2 : to make or burst with a sharp sound a balloon popped 3 : to protrude from the sockets eyes popping with amazement 4 : to shoot with a firearm 5 : to hit a pop fly —often used with up or out pop the question : to propose marriage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the meanings which fit (taken from your list of definitions).

> 3 : to cause to explode or burst open popped some popcorn pop the trunk
>
> 2 : to make or burst with a sharp sound a balloon popped

Either transitive or intransitive, the meaning is the same.